# How can i sort a Collection of objects by ascending LocalTime?

Tags: java

Currently i am trying to do it using a comparator, the "getCurrentTime()" method return a LocalTime.

```
  private final HashMap<Integer, City> cityHashMap = new HashMap<>();
  private final Collection<City> cityCollection = cityHashMap.values();


  public void sortByDepartureTime() {
    List<City> sortedList = new ArrayList<>(cityCollection);
    sortedList.sort(new CityComparator());

    cityCollection.clear();
    cityCollection.addAll(sortedList);
  }


  public static class CityComparator implements Comparator<City> {
    @Override
    public int compare(City o1, City o2) {
      return o1.getCurrentTime().compareTo(o2.getCurrentTime());
    }
  }
```

I am getting a

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException

cityCollection.addAll(sortedList);

I tried using an ArrayList instead of the Collection, but that raised the issue of the ArrayList not being up to date with the HashMap values.

Comment: `cityCollection = cityHashMap.values();` ← That collection belongs to cityHashMap.  You can read it, and you can delete from it, but you cannot directly add to it.  (How would the Map be affected, if that were allowed?  To which key would the new values correspond?)

Comment: What is the goal you are trying to accomplish? Why are you trying to sort the values inside the map? A map "usually" don't have an ordering. Please [edit] your question to include a more detailed description what you are trying to do.

Comment: @VGR ah i understand, thank you, fixed it by using an ArrayList and creating a method that updates the List with the current values in the Map. Thanks again, didnt think about the "Collection belongs to Map" part.

Comment: If the issue was resolved without receiving an answer, consider deleting t he q uestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Answer by Eritrean](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77504532/642706) would be my preferred solution, using a stream. But if you are not yet comfortable with streams, below is the older sort of approach.

### Don’t mess with map’s collected values

In your code:

```
cityCollection.clear();
cityCollection.addAll( sortedList );
```

… `cityCollection` represents the values inside the map. That collection returned by `Map#values` is meant to be read but not written.

Instead, copy that elements of that collection to another collection. You did so correctly in this line:

```
List<City> sortedList = new ArrayList<>( cityCollection );
```

You are then at liberty to manipulate that new `List`.

### `List#sort` with a `Comparator`

As explained by Eritrean, you can define a `Comparator` separate from your `City` class.

Let's define a [record](https://openjdk.org/jeps/395) as the `City` class for our example.

```java
record City( String name , LocalTime localTime ) { }
```

Make some sample data.

```java
Map < Integer, City > map =
        Map.of (
                11 , new City ( "Munich" , LocalTime.parse ( "23:00" ) ) ,
                22 , new City ( "New York" , LocalTime.parse ( "07:00" ) ) ,
                33 , new City ( "Paris" , LocalTime.parse ( "19:00" ) ) ,
                44 , new City ( "London" , LocalTime.parse ( "13:00" ) )
        );
```

Extract a collection of the values from that map, just the `City` objects, by calling [`Map#values`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#values()). Pass that collection to the constructor of an `ArrayList`, a collection type we know we can sort.

```java
List < City > sorted = new ArrayList <> ( map.values ( ) );
```

Now we can perform the sort.

Pass a [method reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html) (`City :: localTime`) to the convenience method [`Comparator.comparing`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html#comparing(java.util.function.Function)) to produce a [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html) object.

```
Comparator.comparing ( City :: localTime )
```

This comparator works because the [`LocalTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api//java.base/java/time/LocalTime.html) class implements [`Comparable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api//java.base/java/lang/Comparable.html). The `LocalTime` objects carry a [`compareTo`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api//java.base/java/time/LocalTime.html#compareTo(java.time.LocalTime)) method to be using in sorting.

In turn we pass that `Comparator` object to the [`List#sort`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#sort(java.util.Comparator)) method.

```java
sorted.sort ( Comparator.comparing ( City :: localTime ) );
```

Dump to console.

```java
System.out.println ( "sorted.toString() = " + sorted );
```

In the result, we see they came out in [the correct order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_York%E2%80%93London%E2%80%93Paris%E2%80%93Munich).

> sorted.toString() = [City[name=New York, localTime=07:00], City[name=London, localTime=13:00], City[name=Paris, localTime=19:00], City[name=Munich, localTime=23:00]]

If returning the result from a method, generally best to (a) return an [unmodifiable](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#unmodifiable) collection, and (b) declare the return type as the more general type [`SequencedCollection`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/SequencedCollection.html) (in Java 21+).

Answer (score 1):

## Stream

If you want to use a Comparator you don't realy need either your method `sortByDepartureTime` nor your class `CityComparator`. Just stream over the values and create a new collection to store the sorted cities:

```
private final HashMap<Integer, City> cityHashMap = new HashMap<>();

....

Collection<City> sorted = cityHashMap.values()
                                     .stream()
                                     .sorted(Comparator.comparing(City::getCurrentTime))
                                     .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

use reversed if you want to sort in reverse order

```
Collection<City> sorted = cityHashMap.values()
                                     .stream()
                                     .sorted(Comparator.comparing(City::getCurrentTime).reversed())
                                     .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: And… In Java 21, we can more descriptively declare the result as a [sequenced collection](https://openjdk.org/jeps/431): `SequencedCollection<City> sorted = …`.